# Anyone knows how to obtain API Access Token for using google rest API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to call google rest api. It's showing 401 unauthorized error. In an example it is said that I should call the API this way: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/1?fields=colorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

My question is how to obtain the API Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you follow the configure your app steps in the calendar documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate and that you read a little about OAuth2 in here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Possibly also try the OAuth2 playground, I found it very useful: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/